# Cstack size limit issue - r

Tags: r

Not able to read MNIST dataset (from dslabs library) due to a C stack limit. R console output is:

```
> mnist <- read_mnist()
Error: C stack usage  15923024 is too close to the limit
```

Unable to implement a solution from forum searches. Closest I can determine is to:

1. (preferable) increase the stack size in terminal and unable to find correct syntax for command line (Windows terminal) or within RStudio terminal.
2. reduce size of raw file (loaded from gz download rather than read_mnist() from the dslabs package.

System: Windows 10, 64bit, RStudio 3.6.3

```
> Cstack_info()["size"]
    size 
15922790
```

... seem to have changed limit in RTools:

```
Dav@DESKTOP-V8I63M1 MINGW64 ~
$ ulimit -s
    2032
Dav@DESKTOP-V8I63M1 MINGW64 ~
$ ulimit -s 16384
Dav@DESKTOP-V8I63M1 MINGW64 ~
$ ulimit -s
    16384
```

... with no effect on the Cstack size in RStudio.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what does `environment(read_mnist)` return? What if you try `mnist <- dslabs::read_mnist()`

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. `mnist <- dslabs::read_mnist()` worked.
Interested in how that overcomes the stack limit issue - if you have time.

Comment: Well, you didn’t say what `environment(read_mnist)` but my guess if you created a recursive function in your environment somehow be designing your own function with the same name. The “C stack usage” error doesn’t have to do with memory necessary, it’s usually caused by infinite recursion. Be careful writing functions with names that match other existing functions.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. Didn't think to include the environment ... which is `<environment: R_GlobalEnv> ... since I was able to load the file. Not building my own function - just using code from a training session. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Yeah, if the environment is the R_GlobalEnv that means you've created a shadow function which was blocking the access to the "real" function. And chances are that function tried to call the "real" function but ended up calling itself causing the infinite loop. You can remove your shadow copy with `rm(read_mnist)` then you could not have to use the explicit namespace prefix.